# Intel BIOS Weird POST Behavior

Tags: bios, freeze, crash

I have two computers exhibiting this behavior. When powering on, post begins and screen shows these characters -- it then freezes.

I'm able to push the <kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd> characters and get a slightly different response (where it starts to load the config screen, do the BIOS flash or load the menu), but it crashes immediately afterwards.

**BIOS Crash Screenshot:**

[image: BIOS Crash Screenshot]

Comment: Is there anyhing more after "Settings" on the first line? What about F12?

Comment: Okay, this got WAY more weird. Machine by itself (connected to direct-connected keyboard and video) posts and boots fine. Machine connected to KVM (adderview) exhibits this behavior -- but only on these two OLD machines (newer stuff handles it just fine).

Comment: @NathanShiraini Same behavior for F12. I can take a picture of the behavior with one of the F keys, but see comment above -- it appears to be the combination of KVM and this OLD BIOS/mobo....

Comment: Were you messing around with NTFS compression by chance?

Comment: If I had to make up a scenario, I would say the BIOS has a buffer overflow while querying hardware? Some BIOS have known overflow vulnerabilities. Perhaps your KVM switch has compatibility options? You don't mention the model.